# BoundField double show as many decimal places as needed

Tags: asp.net, gridview, double, dataformat, boundfield

I have a double variable assigned to a boundfield in a gridview. There will only ever be a max of 5 decimal places.

The boundfield is formatting the display to a scientific value. I'm assuming because it would default to a general format which gives the most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How can i format the number to show only as many decimal places as needed, up to 5. And do not show scientfic notation?

i.e.
0.00002 is currently showing as 2E-05, but I would like it to show as 0.00002.
0.002 should show as that, and not 0.00200.
1 should show that, and not 1.00000. etc.

So a format such as {0:N5} would not work. {0:N} defaults to 2 decimal places, and so would not work either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get what you want with the standard BoundField.DataFormatString codes given the requirement. I think you may have to spin up a custom handler for rendering that particular column and do some custom string formatting tricks to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice @David W
I ended up working it out anyhow.
Although I couldn't find any documentation on it, you can give it proper custom formats.
Therefore, the following solved my issue;

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="theField" DataFormatString="{0:0.#####}" />
```

Comment: Well, I guess I learned something. No point in my irrelevant answer making things more complicated! Have a great day. Glad you got it solved.

Comment: And after a bit of digging (they kinda bury it a little) I found a link to the details for the # specifier. Designed specifically for the purposes of not putting in irrelevant 0's, just as you needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD